# RestAPI JSON Parsing

Tags: android, json

```
            i am new to android. i was search many question,pages,website for my topic. 
            i am trying to parse **RestAPI** like below but i am getting only value which return into below api not exact value from the server.
            please anybody help to how to get exact value from this api. 
            i am new to android. i was search many question,pages,website for my topic. 
            i am trying to parse **RestAPI** like below but i am getting only value which return into below api not exact value from the server.
            please anybody help to how to get exact value from this api. 
                
                        {
                      "name": "JSONWebAPI",
                      "description": "JSON API for android appliation",
                      "url": "http://SG2NWVPWEB022/Services/LoginHandler.ashx",
                      "interfaces": [
                        {
                          "name": "RestAPI",
                          "methods": [
                            {
                              "name": "getProject",
                              "parameters": [
                                {
                                  "name": "projectid",
                                  "type": "int32"
                                }
                              ],
                              "returnvalue": "object"
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "getNews",
                              "parameters": [
                                
                              ],
                              "returnvalue": "object"
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "getAllDownloads",
                              "parameters": [
                                
                              ],
                              "returnvalue": "object"
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "getvideo",
                              "parameters": [
                                
                              ],
                              "returnvalue": "object"
                            },
                          
                                {
                                  "name": "type",
                                  "type": "int32"
                                },
                                {
                                  "name": "requirement",
                                  "type": "int32"
                                }
                              ],
                              "returnvalue": "object"
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "getBrochure",
                              "parameters": [
                                {
                                  "name": "projectid",
                                  "type": "int32"
                                }
                              ],
                              "returnvalue": "object"
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "getGallery",
                              "parameters": [
                                {
                                  "name": "projectid",
                                  "type": "int32"
                                }
                              ],
                              "returnvalue": "object"
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "getWork",
                              "parameters": [
                                {
                                  "name": "projectid",
                                  "type": "int32"
                                }
                              ],
                              "returnvalue": "object"
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "getPlan",
                              "parameters": [
                                {
                                  "name": "projectid",
                                  "type": "int32"
                                }
                              ],
                              "returnvalue": "object"
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "getfacility",
                              "parameters": [
                                {
                                  "name": "projectid",
                                  "type": "int32"
                                }
                              ],
                              "returnvalue": "object"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
       //baseactvity
```

open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
get() = Dispatchers.Main + mJob

```
                        val mJob = Job()
                
                        lateinit var apiService: ApiService
                        lateinit var huntRepository: HuntRepository
                        lateinit var huntViewModel: HuntViewModel
                
                    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                
                        apiService = ApiClient.createService(this)
                        huntRepository = HuntRepository(apiService)
                        huntViewModel = HuntViewModel(huntRepository)
                    }
                    override fun onDestroy() {
                        super.onDestroy()
                        mJob.cancel()
                    }
                }
```

open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
get() = Dispatchers.Main + mJob

```
                        val mJob = Job()
                
                        lateinit var apiService: ApiService
                        lateinit var huntRepository: HuntRepository
                        lateinit var huntViewModel: HuntViewModel
                
                    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                
                        apiService = ApiClient.createService(this)
                        huntRepository = HuntRepository(apiService)
                        huntViewModel = HuntViewModel(huntRepository)
                    }
                    override fun onDestroy() {
                        super.onDestroy()
                        mJob.cancel()
                    }
                }
    
            
//BaseRepository explanining base for android
   

            open class BaseRepository {
                suspend fun <T : Any> safeApiCall(call: suspend () -> Response<T>): Result<T>? {
                    try {
                        val response = call.invoke()
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            val body = response.body()
                            if (body != null) return Result.Success(body)
                        }
                        return error(" ${response.code()} ${response.message()}")
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        return error(e.message ?: e.toString())
                    }
                }
            
                private fun <T : Any> error(message: String): Result<T> {
                    Log.e("API Error :", "===> $message")
                    return Result.Error("Network call has failed for a following reason: $message")
                }
            }

             
//apprepo
   

                class HuntRepository(val api: ApiService) : BaseRepository() {
            
                suspend fun getLogin(body: HashMap<String, String>): Result<LoginData>? {
                    return safeApiCall(
                        call = { api.callLoginAsync(body).await() }
                    )
                }
    
    interface ApiService {
        @POST("Login")
        fun callLoginAsync(@Body body: HashMap<String, String>): Deferred<Response<LoginData>>
    
//result

        sealed class Result<out T: Any> {
            data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
            data class Error(val exception: String) : Result<Nothing>()
        }

      
       
//api

    object ApiClient {
    
        fun createService(context: Context): ApiService {
            return setupRetrofit(context)
                .create(ApiService::class.java)
        }
    
        fun setupOkHttp(context: Context): OkHttpClient {
    
            val cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10 MiB
            val cacheDir = File(context.cacheDir, "HttpCache")
            val cache = Cache(cacheDir, cacheSize.toLong())
            //TODO Replace sample_certificate.pem with your server public certificate in raw resource and uncomment .setupNetworkSecurity(context)
            val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    //            .setupNetworkSecurity(context)
                .cache(cache)
            // if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            builder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            builder.addInterceptor { chain ->
                val original = chain.request()
                val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
    //                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                // Adding Authorization token (API Key)
                val request = requestBuilder.build()
                chain.proceed(request)
            }
            // }
            return builder.build()
        }
    
        private fun setupRetrofit(context: Context): Retrofit {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConstant.Base_Url)
                .client(setupOkHttp(context))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory()) // Using create async means all api calls are automatically created asynchronously using OkHttp's thread pool
                .addConverterFactory(
                    GsonConverterFactory.create(
                        GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(
                            Date::class.java,
                            JsonDeserializer { json, _, _ -> Date(json.asJsonPrimitive.asLong) })
                            .create()
                    )
                )
                .build()
        }
     
    }

    //viewmodel

    

    class HuntViewModel(private val huntRepository: HuntRepository) : BaseViewModel() {
        val loginObserver: MutableLiveData<Result<LoginData>> = MutableLiveData()
    
           val loadObserver: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
    
        suspend fun getLoginRequest(body: HashMap<String, String>) {
            try {
                loadObserver.postValue(true)
                val userResponse = huntRepository.getLogin(body)
                if (userResponse != null) {
                    loginObserver.postValue(userResponse)
                } else {
                    loginObserver.postValue(userResponse)
                }
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
//         ..callapi 
          private fun callLogin(body: HashMap<String, String>) = launch {
            huntViewModel.getLoginRequest(body)
        }
```

Comment: Your server is returning data types not values.

Comment: so how can i get value?

Comment: Rather tagging android, tag a technology on which you wrote server side code.

Comment: `so how can i get value?` - you should ask the guys who developed this REST API. Only they know.

Comment: sorry, for that but i parsing it in android app so i use android tag. and i dnt know this api having which technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution, For this you have to use Volley Library to get data from Server.

Add this line in `build.gradle(Module:app)`

```
dependencies {....
 compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
 }
```

Use this code in Main Activity

```
public void getJsonData() {

    String tag = "get_json";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            "YOUR URL TO GET JSON DATA", new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Get response : " + response);
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                String name = object.getString("name");
                String description = object.getString("description");
                String url = object.getString("url");
                JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("interfaces");
                for (int i = 0;i<array.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name_2 = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    JSONArray methodArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("methods");
                    for (int k=0;k<methodArray.length();k++){
                        JSONObject object_1 = methodArray.getJSONObject(k);
                        String name_3= object_1.getString("name");
                        String returnvalue = object_1.getString("returnvalue");
                        JSONArray parametersArray = object_1.getJSONArray("parameters");
                        for (int j=0;j<parametersArray.length();j++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject_1 = parametersArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            String name_4 = jsonObject_1.getString("name");
                            String type = jsonObject_1.getString("type");
                        }
                    }
                }
         Customelistadapter adapter = new Customelistadapter(MainActivity.this,data1,data3,data2);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();

        }
    });
    request.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {

        @Override
        public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentTimeout() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    request.setShouldCache(false);
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request, tag);
}
```

To run this method you have to add this line in onCreat of MainActivity

```
getJsonData();
```

Create Application Class

```
public class AppController extends Application {
   public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
   public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
     }
  }
```

Now Edit in mainfest.xml inside Application tag add this

```
 <application
    android:name=".AppController">
```

Happy to help...

Comment: giving red underline at **new response.errorlistner** and at last line **appController.....**

Comment: still it giving error at **new Downloader.Response.ErrorListener()** and Appcontroller**.getinstance()**.addtorequestqueue...

Comment: There is no line like new Downloader.Response.ErrorListener() in code

Comment: sorry its my mistake but getting red line under appcontroller.getinstace().addtorequest...

Comment: getinstace() method

Comment: Edit answer - two new method added 1. onCreate() and 2. synchronized. Try now

Comment: but where to write code of binding it to adapter class for display all data

Comment: Welcome, if it helps you, just accept answer and up-vote

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya - Code to bind adapter place after try{} function and above catch{}.

Comment: ya now my code is error free but dnt know where to write adapter binding code to display data?

Comment: Write code here ---> try {..........//ADD CODE FOR ADAPTER//}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace()}.

Comment: can you write edit the code for adapter class binding to display data?

Comment: i mean at which location after which line?

Comment: hi its only give the wtitten value of api not actual value

Comment: What do you mean by "Actual Value"?

Comment: its give the value from the server

Comment: it return only api written data

Comment: i mean data type . so how i get actual value

Comment: i means my api return data type like string, int32 not actual value so how i get actual value from this type of api

Comment: For getting actual values first you have to pass these real values from php side to json and then fetch data from JSON and serve to your listview.

Comment: its come from asp.net side not php side

Comment: its RestAPI webservice of asp.net

Comment: hi @shane its a parameter value which pass to server and get return actual value so do you know how to pass this json as parameter?